# Clojure Korma: How to use where macro in a function?

Tags: clojure, korma

I am trying to use where macro in a function:

```
(defentity student
  (pk :id)
  (table :student)
  (entity-fields :id :name :age :class)
  (database prod))

(defn query-student [cond]
  (select student
    (where cond)))
```

I test it:

```
(select student
  (where {:age [> 13]}))

(query-student '{:age [> 13]})
```

it looks OK, but this

```
(select student
  (where (or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]})))

(query-student '(or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]}))
```

does not work!

```
Failure to execute query with SQL:
SELECT "student".* FROM "student" WHERE (or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]})  ::      []
PSQLException:
 Message: ERROR: syntax error at or near "or"
  Location：42
 SQLState: 42601
 Error Code: 0
PSQLException ERROR: syntax error at or near "or"
  Location：42  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse  (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
```

I want to know why? Something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In Korma, `where` is a macro and as such your second example passes a list literal to it, not giving the macro the opportunity to evaluate the form.

Try changing your `query-student` function to a macro instead, along these lines

```
(defmacro query-student [cond]
  `(select student
    (where ~cond)))
```

As an added bonus, you won't need to quote the form when using the macro:

`(query-student (or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]}))`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Change function to macro is fine. But I want to save (or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]}) in a file and read it before execute. Can I transform the data '(or {:age [> 13]} {:class [in ["1" "2" "3"]]}) to form?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You should just be able to user Clojure's [read](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read) to read your form from the file and pass it along to the macro above. Have you tried that?